# Vista ICS with ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista

I have still have dial-up(cant afford highspeed) and I am trying to configure my desktop with vista to share that connection with Ubuntu Ive got it all setup but ubuntu wont get on the internet at all. Can yall help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Modern network ports supposedly automatically detect if two computers are being connected together directly and set their internals accordingly, but it used to be the case that a special "crossover" cable was required for such a connection - if both your machines are quite old and you can't get any sort of connection this may be the problem.

I assume that you are connecting the two computers together directly, ie not using a router. (If you are using a router plug the Vista machine in the WAN socket and everything should sort itself out.)

Firstly, you need to make sure that the Ubuntu machine can see the Vista machine.

Does the Network Manager (between the clock and the volume control unless you have moved it) show that a connection has been made?

If it does, right click on it and choose connection information. The IP address should be in the form  192.168.0.X, the Default route and Primary DNS should be 192.168.0.1.

If you have no connection, or the numbers above are wrong, make sure that the Ubuntu machine is getting its connection information from the Vista machine. Right click on Network manager and select Edit Connections. Choose the interface and click on Edit. Set it to connect automatically, to be available for all users and to use "Automatic (DHCP)" for IP4 settings.